# Eloquent way to break apart a big class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got a class with a lot of methods. Even after refactoring & pulling out chunks that don't use the `this` context, each method is still a few hundred lines:

```
class BigFella {
  constructor() {
    // lots of stuff
  }

  bigMethod1() {
    // 300 LOCs
  }

  bigMethod2() {
    // 300 LOCs
  }
}
```

It'd be nice to give each method it's own file, but the only way I can think about doing that is something like:

```
import classMethod1 from './classMethod1';
class BigFella {
  constructor() {
    // lots of stuff
  }

  bigMethod1(a,b) {
    return classMethod1.call(this, a,b);
  }
}
```

Is this the best pattern? Any performance impact through using call? Should I just suck it up & have a 2000+ LOC file?

Comment: What are `bigMethod1` and `bigMethod2` doing that requires 300 LOCs? It seems as though you should try to break `BigFella` out into smaller classes, each having a more specific functionality.

Comment: all the methods require the entire `BigFella` context, so breaking it apart is no good. the methods all do some lengthy ast parsing.

Comment: I personally wouldn't sacrifice legibility for line count - if it's all only going to be used as one, rather than modular functions, leave it as one. It will be easier to work with (even if it does mean more scrolling)

Comment: Having a class with a lot of methods may be an indication that an API needs to be split up, but isn't the end of the world. 300 line functions sound pretty scary to me though. I just ran a check on our codebase as an example and of ~6300 methods, only *11* are more than 150 lines and only one is > 300.

Answer (score 1):

In node.js you can mix ES6 and `prototype` form:

Imagine class1.js file:

```
"use strict";

class BigFella {
  constructor() {
    console.log('cons');
  }

  bigMethod1() {
    console.log('big1');
  }

  main() {
    this.bigMethod1();
    this.bigMethod2();
  }
}

module.exports = BigFella;
```

Extendeded in class1b.js file:

```
"use strict";

// import BigFella from './class1.js'; Does not works in nodejs

var BigFella = require('./class1.js');

BigFella.prototype.bigMethod2 = function() {
  console.log('big2');
}

var b=new BigFella();
b.main();
```

Comment: this definitely works, i'm just wondering if there's a way to keep up the facade of classes.

Comment: *"In node.js..."* Not only there. `class` is just syntactic sugar for constructor function and prototype. JavaScript still works how it worked before.